# Notice: Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback() (line 395

Tags: nodes, ajax

Drupal 7.54

Content type with 30 fields and every time a click add more field values nothing happens. I get this in my log file -

Notice: Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback() (line 395 of /home/yourcare/public_html/includes/ajax.inc).

It is driving me nuts it all use to work just fine! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error with "Add another item" button on a taxonomy field with unlimited values recently:

```
Notice: Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback() (line 395 of /www/includes/ajax.inc)
```

Found out that it's an issue with jQuery Update module.
Relevant discussion: https://www.drupal.org/node/2860158

The lastest version of jQuery Update 7.x-3.x-dev fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your php.ini and set max_input_vars = something high.